# How to solve linear system with modulus operation?

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

I came across linear equation $G(x,y) = g_k(x,y) l_k(x,y)$ mod $(y^{2^{k}})$ while reading factoring algorithm [see section 3](http://people.csail.mit.edu/madhu/FT98/lect7.ps) for bivariate polynomials. I need to find the $G(x,y)$ and $l_k(x,y)$.

> **Given** : $g_k(x,y)$, where $deg_y(g_k(x,y)) < y^{2^{k}}$ and $deg_x(g_k(x,y)) < d $.
>
> **Find** : $G(x,y)$ and $l_k(x,y)$. (non trivial)

I know that $G(x,y) = g_k(x,y) l_k(x,y)$ forms a linear system with $y^{2^{k +1}} \times 2d $ many equations and I can solve those equations. But I don't know how to solve correctly $G(x,y) = g_k(x,y) l_k(x,y)$ mod $(y^{2^{k}})$.

> **Here is a problem, suppose after multiplying $g_k(x,y)$ and $l_k(x,y)$, I got a term $y^{2^{k}}$, but after doing mod operation this term is going to become $0$. So my question is, how to resolve this issue.**

Comment: Choose $G = g_k$ and $l_k = 1$. I think you're missing something.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus yes, I have edited my question. I am looking for non trivial $G$ and $l_k$

Comment: You can solve the equation for *every* $l_k$ by calculating $G$ using the formula $G = g_k l_k \bmod{y^{2^k}}$.

Comment: But sill there is a problem that I have mentioned in the second last line.

Comment: Why is terms being 0 a problem? Do you know how to compute modular inverses?

Comment: yes I know how to compute modular inverses. Not only this 0 is a problem but higher degree terms like $y^{2^{k+i}}$, where $i>0$ will going to create problem after doing mod operation

Comment: I still don't see **why** vanishing terms will cause a problem.